# 2 instances of the same program broadcasting via UDPClient

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, udpclient

I'm using UdpClient to broadcast my program location so a centralize computer can find it and start working with it.

It works great, until 2 users on the same computer at the same time try to broadcast.  Since this is a valid use case (think Windows Terminal Server), I'm trying to figure out the best way to address it:

Here is the code I'm currently trying:

```
  m_UDPClients = new List<UdpClient>();
  IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
  foreach (IPAddress ip in localIPs)
  {
    string ipStr = ip.ToString();
    if (!ipStr.Contains("."))  // I only want readable addresses
      continue;

    IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    try
    {
      UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
      udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
      udpClient.Client.Bind(ipLocalEndPoint);
      m_UDPClients.Add(udpClient);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      BSSLog.Error(e);
    }
  }
```

if there is another instance of the program running already, the bind will throw this exception:

```
 An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

This broadcast is just the program 'advertising' some details about how to connect to it's services;  The broadcast happens every few seconds and it's payload is probably < 1k.

I did try to create and destroy the UDPclients as needed and just accept the collision, but it was ugly.

So...the question is:  How do I handle 30 instances of the same program all attempting to advertise themselves via the same UDP port (no listening, just post the payload and move on) on a single computer?

I know I could build a Windows service and play traffic cop, etc... but I'm trying to keep this simple and 'limited user rights' friendly.

Before I run off and attempt to use a predefined system wide named pipe or something, I thought I was ask for help. :)

Comment: What's not working?  You ask how to do it and have a reasonable approach I think, but you don't say what you specifically need help with.

Comment: Can you not generate a hash for an ID and send that along with the broadcast? Say.. a hash of the current time the client was started?

Comment: it appears that the first instance of the program is locking the 'port' from the subsequent instances from connecting to it.  I updated the post to include the exception that is being thrown by the 'Bind'

Comment: Have you tried setting `udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;`?

Comment: I checked in the debugger and udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse is set to false already.

Comment: How about the `ReuseAddress` socket option?  fyi: The default value for `ExclusiveAddressUse` is variable, depending on the OS: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.exclusiveaddressuse(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: I'm doing that with this line: udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with the code.  In our test environment we had a monitoring program that wasn't opening the port correctly.

Good thing we wasted 2 days chasing a red herring.

thank you everyone.